# How to count number of words found in a string in c

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to write a program which counts the number of words found in a string, however the program which I wrote counts the number of spaces. How do I construct this program - as efficient as possible - to count the number of words? What do I do say the string contains 4 words and 8 spaces, or if it contains no words and only spaces? What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
string text = get_string("Text: ");
int count_words = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
{
    if (isspace (text[i]))
    {
        count_words++;
    }
}
printf("%i\n", count_words + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect and count the beginning of words, the space to non-space transition:

```
int count_words = 0;
bool begin = true;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++) {
  if (isspace (text[i])) {
    begin = true;
  } else {
    if (begin) count_words++;
    begin = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain to me what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition to count words:

```
if(text[i]!=' ' && text[i+1]==' ')
        Count=count+1;
```

Comment: If you don't mind explaining what you did? It works, but I don't see why?

Comment: bro i have placed the condition for checking "not a space" and "space after our word" so that we can slice out the word.

Comment: Conditon is : check if there is "not a space" at i. Then check if there is a space after i ,  if its true that means we have sliced out our word. If you still dont get it let me know.

Comment: Dont forget to Mark the answer correct only if you find it helpful.

Comment: If the input does not contain any spaces like `"Hello"`, this approach will report 0 rather than 1.